# React Native import audio file from android res

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm making an Android-only React Native app displaying audio files using [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound), which works well given its `Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE` feature.

For a new sharing feature I need to access my audio files, which are located in the `android/app/src/main/res/raw` folder.

I plan to use [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) and its `url` feature to share it by converting it to base64, implying I need to be able to read the file content.

How can I access these audio files ?

Answer (score 0):

you might have to re-locate them into the web-assets (only could tell how to access them with the `Android AssetManager`). see the [react-native-asset](https://github.com/unimonkiez/react-native-asset) plugin; the `raw` path should be something alike `Uri audioRes = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.acme/raw/filename");` (without suffix).